# Python (pandas): replace value if previous value is same as next value

Tags: python, pandas, outliers

I have the following problem:

I have got a dataframe that could be up to around 6 million rows. On of the columns in this data frame contains certain IDs.

```
ID
NaN
NaN
D1
D1
D1
NaN
D1
D1
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
D2
NaN
D2
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
D3
NaN
D3
NaN
D3
NaN
NaN
```

I want to make the NaNs that is included between the IDs the same as the IDs. Thus above df should become:

```
ID
NaN
NaN
D1
D1
D1
D1
D1
D1
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
D2
D2
D2
NaN
NaN
NaN
NaN
D3
D3
D3
D3
D3
NaN
NaN
```

Does anybody know how to do this in a fast, memory economical way?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `shift` and `loc`. Compare previous and next values using `shift(1)` and `shift(-1)`

```
In [219]: df.loc[df.ID.shift(-1) == df.ID.shift(1), 'ID'] = df.ID.shift(1)

In [220]: df
Out[220]:
     ID
0   NaN
1   NaN
2    D1
3    D1
4    D1
5    D1
6    D1
7    D1
8   NaN
9   NaN
10  NaN
11  NaN
12   D2
13   D2
14   D2
15  NaN
16  NaN
17  NaN
18  NaN
19   D3
20   D3
21   D3
22   D3
23   D3
24  NaN
25  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ffill` and `bfill` - it works also if gap is higher as 1:

```
f = df['ID'].ffill()
df['a'] = df['ID'].mask(f.eq(df['ID'].bfill()), f)
print (df)

     ID    a
0   NaN  NaN
1   NaN  NaN
2    D1   D1
3    D1   D1
4    D1   D1
5   NaN   D1
6    D1   D1
7    D1   D1
8   NaN  NaN
9   NaN  NaN
10  NaN  NaN
11  NaN  NaN
12   D2   D2
13  NaN   D2
14   D2   D2
15  NaN  NaN
16  NaN  NaN
17  NaN  NaN
18  NaN  NaN
19   D3   D3
20  NaN   D3
21   D3   D3
22  NaN   D3
23   D3   D3
24  NaN  NaN
25  NaN  NaN
```